# Divs not staying on point when resizing

Tags: html, css, css-position

Whenever I resize the window the circles go completely out of place even though they're all relative to the same window. Why is that?
They're positioned in the same way, and size in %. 
Any help is very much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div id="product-right">
    <div id="circle-container">
        <div id="circle-1" class="circle" onclick="changeparagraph1()"></div>
        <div id="circle-2" class="circle" onclick="changeparagraph2()"></div>
        <div id="circle-3" class="circle" onclick="changeparagraph3()"></div>
        <div id="circle-4" class="circle" onclick="changeparagraph4()"></div>
        <div id="circle-5" class="circle" onclick="changeparagraph5()"></div>
        <div id="circle-6" class="circle" onclick="changeparagraph6()"></div>
        <div id="circle-7" class="circle" onclick="changeparagraph7()"></div>
        <div id="circle-8" class="circle" onclick="changeparagraph8()"></div>
        <img src="img/gun.svg" alt="gun">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#product #product-right {
    height:100%;
    line-height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    position:relative;
}

#product-right img {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#circle-container {
    height:80%;
    width:80%;
    position:relative;
    margin:3vw 10% 0 10%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.circle {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:#666666;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #666666;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}

#circle-1 {
    top:5vw;
    right:7vw;
}

#circle-2 {
    top:22.5%;
    right:27.5%;
}

#circle-3 {
    top:22.5%;
    right:22.5%;
}

#circle-4 {
    top:31%;
    left:37.5%;
}

#circle-5 {
    top:22.5%;
    right:17.5%;
}

#circle-6 {
    top:50%;
    left:32.5%;
}

#circle-7 {
    top:82%;
    left:24%;
}

#circle-8 {
    top:9%;
    left:28%;
}
```

Comment: try to do this : in the html code edit the img tag to be `<img src="img/gun.svg" alt="gun" class="editdimg">` in the css code add this `img.editimg{ width:auto; }` maybe it wont work but try it .

Comment: Circle move from place because you set position in percentage.. Use table to and try

Comment: @Komal What do you mean "use table"?

Comment: @Laith Thanks for your reply, but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove unwanted css

```
 <div id="product-right">
        <div id="circle-container">
        <table>
          <tr>
          <td>
            <div id="circle-1" class="circle" onclick="changeparagraph1()"></div></td>
          <td>
            <div id="circle-2" class="circle" onclick="changeparagraph2()"></div></td>
          <td>
            <div id="circle-3" class="circle" onclick="changeparagraph3()"></div></td>
          <td>
            <div id="circle-4" class="circle" onclick="changeparagraph4()"></div></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```